# How can I do an animation of an object approaching the camera?

Tags: animation

I am new to blender. I am trying to produce a small 2 second animation of an object approaching a camera and been able to modified to do it from different angles and with different objects (texture, size, shape). Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Path animation could suffice maybe but you should provide an example of what exactly you are trying to achieve in your question.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, path animation comes to mind. Here is a simple example. Please clarify if this is not what you have in mind.

[image]

To set this up, add a curve object to your scene. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>*Curve> Bezier* (or any other curve object).

Next, edit the curve to fit the path you want your object to follow as it moves toward the camera. Here is what my example above looks like from side view.

[image]

Finally, [parent](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html) your object to the curve with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>*>Follow Path* . By default, this will give you 100 frames. If you need to make adjustments, you can do so in the curve properties in the *properties panel.*

[image]

From here, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to play the animation, and  then if needed, make any necessary adjustments.